# Ocultar texto informativo en datatables

Tags: jquery

Tengo un texto que me genera un `datatable`:

> Mostrando registros del 1 al 10 de un total de 23 registros **(filtrado de un total de 127 registros)***

Necesito poder ocultar lo que se encuentra dentro del paréntesis, usando `jQuery`, tendiendo en cuenta que es una cadena completa y su `html` es el siguiente:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataTables_info" id="table_1_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">
  Mostrando registros del 1 al 10 de un total de 23 registros (filtrado de un total de 127 registros)
</div>
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//Primero recuperas la informacion dentro del div:

var tuDiv = $('#table_1_info');

var texto = tuDiv.text();

//Reemplazas lo del texto con una regex:

var newString = texto.replace(/\([^()]*\)/, '');

//y tu nueva cadena no tiene el texto en parentesis 
console.log(newString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dataTables_info" id="table_1_info" role="status" aria-live="polite"> Mostrando registros del 1 al 10 de un total de 23 registros (filtrado de un total de 127 registros) </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era exacto lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocultar esta y otras propiedades de `datatables` desde el archivo de configuración de idioma, desde un archivo index.js o desde el archivo `JS` en el que estás importando los datos. **Debes buscar en cual archivo haces la traducción a español**.

Solo debes pasar un parámetro vacío a la propiedad `infoFiltered` que por defecto trae *- filtered from *MAX* records* o en tu caso *filtrado de un total de *MAX* registros*. Así por ejemplo:

```
$('.claseDeLasTablas').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "infoFiltered": ""
  }
} );
```

Mas información al respecto, en la [documentación oficial](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.infoFiltered)

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes poner el parametro info igual a false y ya

```
$('#tablaEjemplo').dataTable({
  info: false
});
```

Comment: OP pide ocultar _lo que se encuentra dentro del paréntesis_, no toda la info. Allí sería acertado lo que propone [_DjCrazy_](/users/40877) en su [respuesta](/a/585931).